# Scrollable autocomplete drop down list with default suggestions in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've found a few different options for autocomplete drop down lists, but none seem to do exactly what I want and I'm wondering if there's another option that might work better for me (or a way I can customize one of the below plugins to fit my needs).

First option is the [Autocomplete Plugin using jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote). The problem with this plugin is that it's just an autocompleting text box. If the user just clicks on the box, there is no drop down and no suggestions until they type something.

Second option is the [Twitter Typeahead Plugin](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/). This plugin seems to be a little bit better of a fit because it has a bunch of customization options. It has a [Default Suggestions](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#default-suggestions) option which is nice, but I'm using the dropdown for choosing a state and I want it to be a pure dropdown menu if nothing is typed into the textbox and it seems a bit tedious to set all 50 states as the default options.

Third option is [complete.ly](http://complete-ly.appspot.com/playground/code.playground.html) which seems to be the best option except the drop down list doesn't go away when you click out of the text box.

Also I'd prefer if it didn't *filter* the options as the user types, but rather just highlighted the first option that fits the inputted text. For example, if the user types in "C", I want it to highlight "CA" for them, followed by "CO", "CT", "DE", and so on. This is somewhat minor of a preference, the main goal is a drop down menu that:

1. Drops down when you click on the text box and not sooner
2. Shows the full list of states to scroll through/select before anything is typed
3. (Optional) Doesn't filter out options that don't fit what's typed in the text box, but rather just scrolls down to and highlights the first option in the list that fits what's typed.

Comment: Why don't you use select2. Its pretty easy.

Comment: @BasantaMatia that definitely seems better than my 3 options. Unfortunately it filters out options so it's not *perfect* but thanks for the suggestion I might end up using that!

Comment: Have a look at it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49790265/8494462